# How to get the edge value of a graph in graph-tool library?

Tags: python, graph, graph-tool

I am working on a project where I have to manipulate graphs. I am using graph-tool library for which I am new and I code using Python 2.7.

I added a new edge property called `edge_capacity`. For some reason, I need to know to which edge that value belongs to and the vertices that form that edge.

Thank you for pointing me out to a solution.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is useful to know what you have already tried but knowing not much about your actual problem here is one suggestion: the first part could be achieved using `find_edge`. So if you needed `edge_capacity=5` your solution could look like something along these lines:

```
es = gt.find_edge(g,edge_capacity,5)
for e in es:
    v1 = e.source()
    v2 = e.target()
```